# how to send file to http server through http request

Tags: c, http

i have to write c program for client such that it send xml file to server via http.i google up but can't understand .i have made socket program which send data from client to server but now we have to send file through http request.
i have to send file text/xml from client to .net based server through http request.

Comment: Hello on SO! Please refer to the FAQ to understand what types of questions are likely to be answered. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Many solutions are implementation dependant. What OS are you using?

Comment: working on windows xp using vs2008, without using libcurl can it posible.

Comment: The real question you're asking is "how do I write my own http client", and the answer is to familiarize yourself with the relevant W3C documents describing HTTP and then implementing those parts you need. I'm not sure what you wanted, someone to write your program for you?

Comment: my quest. is little bit change actually before this issue i send the user,pwd from client to http server for verification in which i generate the query string(containing usr,pwd) and send req. to server.But now i have to send file(text/xml) to that server , idon't know who it can be done .is we have to write some code to server or only in client. how server take file via url only.

Comment: check the url http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/281070 it's near by solution but it's for php and i have to do in visual stdio .net ..how it can be done ??

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question that whether you want to post the XML data or you want to send the XML file as an attachment to the server (An opportunity to raise a "File Download" dialogue box for a known MIME type with binary format or suggest a filename for dynamic content. Quotes are necessary with special characters).

If you need to post the XML content to the Server simply read the XML file from your code apply http header over it & send it to the server.

If you need to send XML file as a downloadable content read MIME & HTTP headers.